# How to pass multiple condition in a firebase query in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add another conditon to my firebase query. I want to say userID = xx and status = yy.
Is there any way to do that in same query?

```
static Future<List<Ticket>> ticketDataStream(userID) async {
    final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;

    List<Ticket> tickets = List<Ticket>();

    await for (var snapshot in databaseReference
        .collection('bets')
        .where('userID', isEqualTo: userID)
        .snapshots()) {
      for (var document in snapshot.documents) {
        Ticket ticket = Ticket();

        ticket.status = document.data['status'];
        ticket.numOfMatches = document.data['numOfMatches'];
        ticket.returnAmount = document.data['return'];
        ticket.totalOdds = document.data['odds'];
        ticket.dateTime = document.data['dateTime'].toDate();
        ticket.betAmount = document.data['betAmount'];
        ticket.ticketID = document.documentID;

        tickets.add(ticket);
      }

      return tickets;
    }
    return null; //TODO: be sure that is not a problem
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried multiple where in query like ```.where('userID', isEqualTo: userID).where('status', isEqualTo:status)```. ?

Comment: nope, thanks. What if I want to make an "or" condition instead of "and"?

Comment: OR conditions are not possible with Firestore. You'll have to fire multiple queries, and merge the results client-side. Note that **IN** queries **are** supported. See the third bullet point here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations

Comment: @kishanvekariya What you wrote sounds like the start of a great answer. Want to write it, so we can upvote/accept it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try to use multiple .where like

```
databaseReference
    .collection('bets')
    .where('userID', isEqualTo: userID)
    .where('status', isEqualTo:status)
```

Comment: Is it possible to use two `where`s?